# How to get selected items from listbox for SQL where statement

Tags: vb.net

How do you get the selected items from the listbox so that I can use it on my SQL where statement... selected items wont work because it shows datarowview.. I've tried using

```
Dim Studente As String = ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItems())
```

But it didn't do anything

Comment: `.GetItemText(ListBox1.SelectedItem)`, single. If you want to get the text of more than one item, you have to iterate the `SelectedItems` collection (which is a property, not a method).

Comment: Show how you populate listbox with items

Comment: If you set `Option Strict` to `On` - you will get type checking help during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific:

```
Dim students As String() = ListBox1.SelectedItems.
                                    Cast(Of Object)().
                                    Select(Functions(item) ListBox1.GetItemText(item)).
                                    ToArray()
```

Without LINQ:

```
Dim students As New List(Of String)

For Each item In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    students.Add(ListBox1.GetItemText(item))
Next
```

You can then call `ToArray` on that `List` if you specifically need an array.

Comment: It says here that value of 1-dimensional array of string cannot be converted to string

Comment: *"1-dimensional array of string cannot be converted to string"*. You did it wrong. You should have actually checked to see if you did what I did and, if you got that message, you clearly didn't. In my first code snippet, I declared `students` as type `String()`, i.e. `String` array. The error message indicates that you didn't do that, despite my having posted the exact code you needed.

Comment: *"The items on the list are from a binded data source"*. That doesn't matter in this particular scenario.

Comment: I'll try again Thank you

Comment: do I need to type both the code you posted?? Or only one??

Comment: I wanted to use this code for a method below it which is UpdateLV(Students)

Comment: The students inside the method part is whatsays the error I'm typing the suggestion you posted correctly and I followed it

Comment: You only need to use one or the other of the suggestions I provided. If you have now changed what you are doing but are still having the issue then update your question with all the relevant information. If we can see what you're doing, we can see what you're doing wrong. Please be sure to format your code as code, which I have done in my answer but you did not do in your question.

Comment: Please also note that getting the data out of the `ListBox` has nothing to do with SQL code. If your issue is using the data you get out of the `ListBox` then that is a separate question.

Comment: That said, you may benefit from reading [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298-Using-Parameters-with-an-SQL-IN-Clause).